# Web Part Javascript Object or Method Not Supported

Tags: javascript, web-part

I'm trying to show a javascript clock in a SharePoint Web Part.

In the .ascx file, I have the following code:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WorldClockUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestClock.WorldClock.WorldClockUserControl" %>

<canvas id="abcdef" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("abcdef");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;

    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    var radius = radius * 0.90;
    drawClock();
    setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

    function drawClock() {

        drawFace(ctx, radius);
        drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
        drawTime(ctx, radius);

    }

    function drawFace(ctx, radius) {

        var grad;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        ctx.fill()

        var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
        grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
        grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
        ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
        ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();

    }

    function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {

        var ang;
        var num;
        ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
            var ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
            ctx.rotate(ang);
            ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
            ctx.rotate(-ang);
            ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
            ctx.rotate(ang);
            ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
            ctx.rotate(-ang);
        }
    }

    function drawTime(ctx, radius) {

        var now = new Date();
        var hour = now.getHours();
        var minute = now.getMinutes();
        var second = now.getSeconds();

        //hour
        var hour = hour % 12;
        var hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) + (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) + (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
        drawHand(ctx, hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07, "grey");

        //minute
        var minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
        drawHand(ctx, minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07, "black");

        // second
        var second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
        drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02, "red");
    }

    function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width, colour) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = colour;
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(pos);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.rotate(-pos);
    }

</script>
```

Whenever I run the solution and the page tries to load the web part, an exception is thrown when it tries to run the "beginPath()" method, saying it's not supported.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe because you are trying to pass an argument of `ctx`, remove that argument because your context is global. The runtime engine may be using the argument variable instead of global.

Comment: @Mike unfortunately that didn't work, sorry, still breaks when it tries to run ctx.beginPath() in the drawFace function!

Comment: What browser are you using? Also you don't have to use any arguments on any of those functions because `ctx` and `radius` are both global variables in this case. Also change the second `var radius = radius * 0.90;` to just `radius = radies * 0.90;`, you can't declare a new variable twice.

Comment: @Mike I'm using IE11 on Win Server 2012R2, but currently the server is down so I can't test it.. I'll let you know if removing var and the arguments works!

Comment: @Mike still not working unfortunately - strangely enough I can see it draw the clock before it then errors out on beginPath() and then it won't let me switch to the IE page once it throws an exception

Comment: I'd break it down outside of the functions, and also try another file with just the base and see if it's because it's in a SharePoint aspx page. Try adding a Content Editor webpart manually and adding the code you have.

Comment: @Mike if I put the script directly in an HTML file and run it through Chrome, it functions fine. I've then linked a Content Editor to that file, and the canvas draws as it should but the setInterval isn't firing (same with entering the script straight into a Script Editor). The problem is, I also need some server side code running which is why this was originally an SP feature